# How do I count AdjacentDuplicates using the Scanner Object?

Tags: java, count, duplicates

The problem is that the output I'm having is counting an extra unknown Adjacent that I'm unfamiliar off.

(Work Problem) - static int adjacentDuplicatesCount(String str) – returns the count of duplicates that are next to each other. Given "1 1 2 7 7 7 7 3 3 5 3", return 3.`

From my understanding I'm assuming that ("11") , ("7777"), and ("33") are the three counts in this string above. I don't have much knowledge on any other way to do this as I'm still a beginner.

Code Below:

```java
public static int adjacentDuplicatesCount(String str) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(str);
        String result = "";
        int count = 0;

        while(reader.hasNext()){
            result+= reader.next();
        }



        for (int i = 1; i < result.length() -1; i++) {
            if (result.charAt(i) == result.charAt(i + 1)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

```
Desired Output 3 == 3

My Output 4 == 3
```

I have been noted that I could add another for loop in the main loop, however I'm not entirely sure how that could help. Others suggested that I should state "while its the same character, don't do anything" although this too  is a confusing solution to me, that I'm not sure how I would write it.

Comment: With ` 7 7 7 7` you only want to count this as one group.  Maybe you need another variable which is keeping track of the group that you are dealing with.  Analyzing the problem is key.

Comment: I see, but how would this help me further get to my desired result?

Comment: *" I'm assuming that ("11") , ("7777"), and ("33") "* What  is the source of the problem? If you are not sure what the requirements are, you should ask the teacher, professor, or whomever to clarify. If this is a problem found on the web, please provide a link.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not the best at  clarifying things . I'm not sure why I'm getting an output of 4 instead of 3. Nor do I know how to fix it.

Comment: You have 3 groups i.e. `1`, `7`, and `3` - do not count then again.  In my first comment I gave you a suggestion how to do this.

Comment: You're right, sorry for not seeing it sooner. I appreciate the suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want get the count of duplicates, i think you can do it like this:

```
public static int adjacentDuplicatesCount(String str) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(str);
    int count = 0;
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String next = reader.next();
        // Only the first duplication is counted
        if (map.containsKey(next) && map.get(next).equals(1)) {
            count++;
        }
        map.put(next, map.getOrDefault(next, 0) + 1);

    }
    return count;
}
```

Given "1 1 2 7 7 7 7 3 3 5 3", your code just counts '7777':

```
for (int i = 1; i < result.length() -1; i++) {
    if (result.charAt(i) == result.charAt(i + 1)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```